# three.js / A-Frame ObjectLoader does not load Texture and positions Meshes wrongly

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, blender, cinema-4d

We have an issue with exporting our 3D Assets and animations correctly so that three.js can correctly display them.

All our 3D artists work with Cinema4D so we need to go through blender to export a three.js compatible JSON. They export the scene as FBX and then import it to blender. This seems to work fine. The model looks good there (with Material View set in Preview Window) and the simpler models we exported even worked with textures and animations.

But we now have a scene where, when we load the resulting JSON, some of the meshes are flipped 180° (but only some - the trees) and one of the models (Santa model) is not textured. They all look fine in blender.

When loading the JSON in https://threejs.org/editor/ you will immediately see the issues:

[image]

Is this an export problem? Can we fix it by tweaking the export params? Will we need to adjust the model in blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise a couple things here:

1. [File a bug on three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/new) including the `.blend` file
2. Try freezing transforms in Blender or C4D before export
3. Perhaps try a different three.js-compatible blender exporter, like [glTF-Blender-Exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. We switched over to the glTF Blender Exporter and it worked perfectly on the first try. Using the three.js JSON Exporter might be a bad idea when there are Github issues with titles like "Blender exporter sucks" ;)